# How to create scrollable element in Tailwind without a scrollbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to recreate a horizontal scroll navbar with tailwind *without a scrollbar* on the bottom like this example (reduce the width of your screen to be able to scroll)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/blog/

I tried the following using Tailwind but I wasn't able to figure out how to remove the horizontal scrollbar that appears like the bootstrap example above. Could someone help?

```
<ul class="flex overflow-x-auto whitespace-nowrap p-4">
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="p-2">Nav Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To hide the scrollbar you'll need to style it directly:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.no-scrollbar {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

You could easily add these as Tailwind utilities using a plugin in your config: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-utilities

---

**Further reading:**

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp

Comment: That worked! Is there a different way that Bootstrap hides scrollbars? I dug into the Bootstrap example I posted above and I can't find the css code that does -webkit-scrollbar or -ms-overflow-style or scrollbar-width

Comment: So interestingly in the bootstrap example it's just achieved with a defined height on the outer div that hides the scrollbar! Took me a few mins to get there.

Comment: Hi I want to try this answer but how to add `no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar` to plugins `::-webkit-scrollbar` this line makes me confuse. Could you write a sample for adding -webkit-scrollbar to `tailwind.config.js` that would be very helpful to me.

Comment: `::-webkit-scrollbar` is just a webkit specific selector used to target the scrollbar style in Chrome, Safari, Edge and Opera. The class that can be used here is `.no-scrollbar`. https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar. As far as adding a utility in TailwindCss I'd use the approach here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/zQftpiBCmf

Answer (score 61):

Add this to your global css file (`global.css`, `style.css` or whatever you have):

```css
/*
    https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2394
    https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/5732
*/
@layer utilities {
    /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    .no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }

    .no-scrollbar {
      -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
      scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    }
}
```

Then you just add the class `no-scrollbar` as you would typically like so, notice I added overflow-y-auto to keep the scrollbar automatically the correct size too.

```
<div className="no-scrollbar overflow-y-auto">
```

ALTERNATIVELY:

You could try this `tailwindcss` plugin for hide scrollbar

https://github.com/reslear/tailwind-scrollbar-hide

Comment: From this answer I cannot deduct in which file should I put this class definition

Comment: You are welcome ;D

Comment: I love to use this approach, with a note that if we use a prefix for our tailwind classes, this layer will not need a prefix. Please CMIIW :)

Answer (score 21):

To answer @wataru's question in the comments, **the syntax to add these classes as a plugin** to `tailwind.config.js` is this:

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx}",
  ], 
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.scrollbar-hide': {
          /* IE and Edge */
          '-ms-overflow-style': 'none',

          /* Firefox */
          'scrollbar-width': 'none',

          /* Safari and Chrome */
          '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
            display: 'none'
          }
        }
      }
      )
    })
  ],
}
```

The lines to inspect are the `const plugin` and the `plugins: []` array

I learned this by inspecting the source code of the https://github.com/reslear/tailwind-scrollbar-hide package linked by @jasonleonhard above.

Answer (score 12):

With tailwind v3 you are able to use arbitrary values to achieve this.

Use `[&::-webkit-scrollbar]:hidden` on your HTML element classList.

Answer (score 6):

Tailwind v3 has a powerful feature called`arbitrary values`. You can find how to use it here, [Using arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants). Read slowly because you can miss it. I did the first time. There's no need to use utilities.

`class="[&::-webkit-scrollbar]:hidden [-ms-overflow-style:none] [scrollbar-width:none]"`

That takes care of the big 3 browsers:

/* Safari and Chrome */

/* IE and Edge */

/* Firefox */

Comment: should be [scrollbar-width:none] i.e none should be without single quotes